# InnerHTML- fetching from script

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, innerhtml

I am trying to display random numbers from 1 to 7. I do not want them to repeat and I want to display every number. I've written my JS code inside `script` tag. I want to get a random number whenever `button` is clicked, instead I'm getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at grandom (fe.html:48)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (fe.html:25)
```

Below is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Goplan Project Selection</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sign-in/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="text-center">
        <img src="cissoiree.jpg" width="80px" height="80px">
    <h1 style="text-size:300em">Go-Plan</h1></div></div>
    <div style="padding-top:20px;" class="text-center">
      <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="grandom()">Click!</button>
      <p id="demo"><p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    function grandom()
    {
    var q=[2,3,1,5,4,7,6];
    var x=7;
    var i;
    x=q.length;
    var random;
            while(1)
            {

                random = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
                if(random<=q.length)
                break;
            }
            document.write("<br>");
            document.write("Question No : " + q[random] );
            if(q.length!=1)
            <!--document.write("<input type=button value=click here onclick=grandom();><br>");-->
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = q[random];
            q.splice(random,1);     
            document.write("<br>");
     }
     </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `document.write(...);` there is no other elements in the page expect the passed text.

It is why when you trying to find then `document.getElementById("demo")` it's cannot find, and return `null`. (then throw error, when you trying to access its `innerHTML`)

If you trying to append something to the page you should use `document.body.innerHTML += "..."`.

About the algorithm itself - you can use:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].sort(function() { return .5 -Math.random();});
```

It will shuffle the array randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `document.write(..)` is breaking it.

You can try:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<br />';
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Question No : ${q[random]}`;
document.body.innerHTML += '<br />';
```

Comment: why did you append `<br/>` to the end of body, if the random number is not appended there, but  in the existing element, somewhere in the middle of the page